# Changing the data in before submit

Tags: jquery, servlets, ajaxform

I am using the ajaxForm plugin found [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Now i have a **form** with **username** & **password**

My requirement is to change the value of **password** field to its **md5** so for that I am using the plugin found [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/md5)

so for that I am using like this :

```
$('myForm').ajaxForm({

   url : 'pathtosend',
   type : 'post',
   beforeSubmit : function(arr, $form, options){
      $('#password').val($.md5($('#password').val()));
   },
   success : function(response, statusText, xhr, $form){
      alert('blah blah');
   }
});
```

Now when I print the value of **password** in **java servlet code** it shows the one that I passed and not the md5 of the value as I did.

When I changed the coding to the click of the **submit** button and manipulating the submit its done so my question is what is the significance of **beforeSubmit** when the data changed is not going to **reflect** in the **submit**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to change your beforeSubmit function to this:

```
    beforeSubmit : function(arr, $form, options){
      arr.push({name:'hashed-password', value:$.md5($('#password').val())})
   },
```

Then you can access the hashed-password variable in your servlet.

The reason for this is that the value from the text input has already been processed by AjaxForm and stored in the arr array.

Edit: if you don't want to send the plaintext password, you can use your original method but change `beforeSubmit : function(arr, $form, options){` to `beforeSerialize : function() {`

Comment: how would i use this to submit a file instead and change the default name?? I am trying to submit a blob recorded in the browser. (default name is just blob when i submitted it using a FormData its easy to change name with formdata `fd.append('name_in_form', new_recording, "browser_recording.mp3");` )

Comment: I am also getting a javascript error: arr.push is not a function.